# How to check if number is even using recursive function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I am trying to do an exercise from here https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-recursion-function-exercise-7.php

I understand the solution, however, I am kind of curious why my program does not yield the same answer as above. The way I choose the return the function is slightly different, however, it yields a number instead of true or false.

```js
function checkeven(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (num === 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log(num);
        return num - checkEven(num - 2);
    }
}

   
console.log(checkeven(8));
console.log(checkeven(9));
```

Comment: you finally subtract a boolean value. which value do you expect after using a subtraction?

Comment: `return num - checkeven(num - 2)` -> `return checkeven(num - 2)`

Comment: `return num - checkeven(num - 2);` should be `return checkeven(num - 2);`

Comment: `Improve this sample solution`  Don't use recursion, :)

Comment: The strangest use case of recursion I ever seen

Comment: @NinaScholz - thank you, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code had issue since you we trying to subtract from a boolean value , Due to which type corecion occurs as per the rules given under ecmascript guidlines.(https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours)

you can go with the following solution:

```
  (function fixthis() {
      function checkeven(num) {

          if (num === 0) {
              return true;
          } else if (num === 1) {
              return false;
          } else {

              let Tempnum = num - 2;
              if (checkeven(Tempnum)) {
                  return true;

              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          }
      }
      console.log(checkeven(8));
      console.log(checkeven(9));

  })()
```

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript - when the operands to an operator are of different types - type corecion happens, i.e it tries to convert one of the operands into a type that is compatible with the operator

Try this:
`console.log(2 + true) //3`

`console.log(true + false) //1`

In your case, consider what happens when you try `checkeven(2)`

`checkeven(2) = 2 - checkeven(0) = 2 - true = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `return num - checkeven(num - 2)` with `return checkeven(num - 2)` in your code.

```js
function checkeven(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (num === 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return checkeven(num - 2);
    }   
} 
console.log(checkeven(8));
console.log(checkeven(9));
```

Answer (score 1):

Concocted a solution with both positive and negative numbers!

```js
  var isEven = function (n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    return positive(n);
  } else {
    return negative(n);
  }

  function negative(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
      return true;
    } else if (num === -1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return isEven(num + 2);
    }
  }

  function positive(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
      return true;
    } else if (num === 1) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return isEven(num - 2);
    }
  }
};

console.log(isEven(9));
console.log(isEven(8));
console.log(isEven(-8));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
odd = function(n) {if (n%2 == 0) {return true} else {return false;}}

console.log(odd(8));
console.log(odd(5));
```

or:

```js
checkeven = function(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
        return true;
    } else if (num === 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return checkeven(num - 2);
    }
}
             
console.log(checkeven(8));
console.log(checkeven(9));
```

Comment: You can just use `let odd = (num%2 == 0)` or `return (n%2 == 0)` without using the conditional operator.

Comment: :) you're right. So I thought that you can see how it works.

Comment: Result is correct, but it doesn't answer the question

Comment: OK, you're right, but partial answer is already in what I've posted. Function has no return value except numbers and return must call the callback function again ... So approximately: checkeven = function (num) {
   if (num === 0) {
     return true;
   }
   else if (num === 1) {
     return false;
   }
   else {
     n = num -2;
     return checkeven (n);
   }
}

   
console.log (check even (8));
console.log (check even (9));

Comment: In this case n becomes a global variable, you can just put directly in the return ` num - 2`

Answer (score 0):

`return checkeven(num-2);`, returns a boolean value. You are trying to subtract a boolean value from a number, which won't work. Your code will work just fine if you remove `num-checkeven(num-2)*` and replace it with `checkeven(num-2);`

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the modulo operator, so you don't even need recursion

```
const areYouEven = n => !(n % 2)
```

Comment: Could be comment on the main question; fails to address the actual issue or honor the requirements per the linked exercise.